# C++ map, switch, and main menu trouble

Tags: c++, dictionary, menu, switch-statement

When I run my Main Menu, I am able to add data that is needed for the map, but the problem happens when I go back to the menu and find that when I try to print the data nothing appears. In case you are wondering, there are no errors, it will just not print the data stored within the map when you run print contacts from the menu. Below is the code.

### Main

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "AddContact.h"


//PASSWORD IS "Delta" use upper case D and the rest is lower case
int main() {
    AddContact con;
    con.Menu();

    return 0;
}
```

### AddContact.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

#ifndef ADDCONTACT_H_
#define ADDCONTACT_H_

class AddContact {
public:
    std::map<int, AddContact> people;
private:
    string ContactName;
    long long ContactPhone;
    string Address;
    string Email;
    string Skype;

public:
    AddContact();
    AddContact(string ContactName, long long ContactPhone, string Address, string Email, string Skype);
    void ADD();
    void print()const;
    void view();
    void Menu();
    void Password();
};

#endif /* ADDCONTACT_H_ */
```

### AddContact.cpp

```
#include "AddContact.h"
AddContact::AddContact(): ContactName(""), ContactPhone(0), Address(""), Email(""), Skype(""){

}
AddContact::AddContact(string ContactName, long long ContactPhone, string Address, string Email, string Skype) {
    this->ContactName = ContactName;
    this->ContactPhone = ContactPhone;
    this->Address = Address;
    this->Email = Email;
    this->Skype = Skype;
}
void  AddContact::Password(){
    cout << "Please Enter Your Password. " << endl;
        string pass;
        cin >> pass;
        if (pass != "Delta") {
            Password();
        }
}
void  AddContact::Menu(){

    cout << "!!MyCircle Contact!!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    Password();
    int selection;
    do {
        cout << "***************************" << endl;
        cout << "1. Add New Contact         " << endl;
        cout << "2. Display Contact      " << endl;
        cout << "3. Quit                    " << endl;
        cout << "***************************" << endl;
        cin>> selection;
        switch(selection){
        case 1:
            ADD();
            break;
            view();
            break;
        }
    } while (selection != 0);



}
void AddContact::ADD() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        string temp1;
        cout << "Please Enter Contact Name: " << endl;
        cin >> temp1;
        long long temp2;
        cout << "Please Enter Contact Phone Number: " << endl;
        cin >> temp2;
        int choice;
        cout<< "Press 1 if you would like to add additional contact info or press 0 to return to main menu "<< endl;
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 1) {
            string temp3 = "";
            cout << "Please enter contact Address: " << endl;
            cin>> temp3;
            getline(cin, temp3);
            string temp4= "";
            cout << "Please enter contact Email: " << endl;
            cin >> temp4;
            string temp5 = "";
            cout << "Please enter contact Skype: " << endl;
            cin >> temp5;
            people[i] = AddContact(temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5);
    } else {

    }
}
}
void AddContact::print()const{
    cout<<ContactName<<" "<<ContactPhone<<" "<<Address<<" "<<Email<<" "<<Skype<<endl;
}
void AddContact::view(){
    for(map<int, AddContact>::iterator it = people.begin(); it != people.end();it++){

            it->second.print();
        }
}
```

Comment: Your class `AddContact` contains as member a `std::map<int, AddContact>`. Does this compile?

Comment: This code can surely be reduced to a better [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I appreciate the visual aid diasalle and thank you Walter for showing me how the code should have been posted, I voted for your change request.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mising a `default` in your switch statement:

```
switch(selection){
    case 1:
        ADD();
        break;
        view();
        break;
}
```

is mean to be

```
switch(selection){
    case 1:
        ADD();
        break;
    default:
        view();
        break;
}
```

Comment: OMG man it worked. I love you!!!! In C++ is there always a default needed after the break? for all cases? for example case 1 break default, case 2 break default, case 3 break default and so on?

Comment: Default catches whatever is not caught by a `case` statement -- so you only have at most one. In your previo uscode, your first break made the `view()` unreachable.